# What is the meaning of "called outside of transaction" in the Hibernate persist method documentation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, persist

From the hibernate documentation:

> persist() makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does not
>   guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent
>   instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time.
>   persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement
>   if it is called outside of transaction boundaries. This is useful in
>   long-running conversations with an extended Session/persistence
>   context.

This line "persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries." seems to be confusing. If we called the persist(), then it is already part of the session. Then why does the question of "outside of transaction" arrive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A session and a transaction lifecycles are identical only for session-per-request, albeit the most used session management pattern.

But Hibernate is flexible and it also supports long conversations, when a Session is reused across multiple web requests. This is similar to Java EE extended persistence context with statefull EJB.

In a long conversation, the db connections are released when the client thread gets out if the service layer, and the session is not automatically flushed anymore.

It's the last request that could run in a writable Transaction which would sync all state changes to the db.

Comment: what is outside a transaction means? Is it mean that the code which executes after executing session.getTransaction().commit()

Comment: It means code that is not executed within begin/end calls.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Could ypu please explain my similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699264/what-is-a-transaction-boundary-in-hibernate/71699404#71699404
thanks